# How to use Check All option in nglightning in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, datatables, angular2-template

I need an option in nglightning to checkall records in datatable. The link for the component is as following

> https://ng-lightning.github.io/ng-lightning/#/components

In the header row I need an option to check all checkboxes in nglightning.

Answer (score 0):

I tried [] or [()] data binding first but it did not work. Created an ugly solution. You may need to ask ng-lighting why data binding does not work in column template.

Here is the Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/zNrWb4Ui2LVXc5fJb1oY?p=preview

Code I added:

```
<ngl-datatable-column heading="" key="points">
    <template nglDatatableHeading><input type="checkbox" (click)="toggleCheckAll()" /></template>
    <template nglDatatableCell><input type="checkbox" class="child-chkbox" /></template>
</ngl-datatable-column>

toggleCheckAll(){
    var chkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('child-chkbox');
    this.checkAll = !this.checkAll;

    for(let i = 0; i < chkboxes.length; i++){
        chkboxes[i].checked = this.checkAll;
    }
}
```

Comment: Although my designing issue is resolved but now I am getting error "Property 'checked' does not exist on type Element'." in chkboxes[i].checked line.

Comment: @MunishSharma add `declare global {interface Document { getElementsByClassName('child-chkbox'): HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLInputElement>; } }`

Comment: It is a type declaration, just put that at the top level, right after your component.

Comment: That is, somehow, I don't like TypeScript. It kills Javascript's freedom.